# Can I use flat shading on a generated mesh?

Tags: unity, procedural-generation, mesh, shading

I tried to generate a mesh from code in Unity. The problem is, that the edges are automatically smoothed. When I import a model into Unity, I can set the smoothing angle of the edges, but is something like this possible with a generated mesh?

I would like to have no smoothing at all.

Comment: If anyone is looking, this tool can harden edges and smooth edges, along with the entire mesh.
[https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/slug/166155](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/slug/166155) It also has a bunch of other modeling tools if you wanted to edit your generated mesh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal for a vertex is generated by taking the mean of the normals for each face that contains that vertex.

As such if a mesh contains two (or more) triangles that share vertices they will be displayed with a smoothed edge.

If you use separate vertices (they can have identical positions) then they will be displayed with a hard edge.

There is some coverage of this topic on Morten Nobel's blog post on procedurally generating meshes over [here](http://blog.nobel-joergensen.com/2010/12/25/procedural-generated-mesh-in-unity/).